# Why the plural in "être sidérés" ?

Tags: grammaire, accord, pluriel, subordonnées

Why is it `être sidérés` and not `être sidéré` in this sentence?

> Impossible de ne pas être sidérés, cette semaine

The [full quote](https://www.franceculture.fr/medias/invasion-du-capitole-inceste-astrologie-et-jacques-prevert-la-session-de-rattrapage) is:

> Bonjour à toutes et à tous,
>
> Impossible de ne pas être sidérés, cette semaine, devant les folles images du Capitole, à Washington D.C., envahi par les partisans de Donald Trump.

Answer (score 4):

“*[Il est] impossible [pour X] de* ⟨infinitive clause⟩” is another way of saying “*Il est impossible que X* ⟨subjunctive clause⟩”. In both cases, X is the semantic subject of the subordinate clause. With *de* + ⟨infinitive clause⟩, the subordinate clause has a verb in the infinitive mood, which does not have an explicit subject, so it's possible for X to be fully implicit in the sentence. With *que* + ⟨subjunctive clause⟩, the subordinate clause has an explicit subject, so X has to be explicit in the sentence.

In the infinitive case, there is no explicit subject, but the verb and other parts of the sentence still needs to agree with the semantic subject X. In your example, the clause consists of the verb *être* in the infinitive present and a predicative adjective (*[attribut du sujet](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribut_(grammaire)#Attribut_du_sujet)*) *sidéré*. (I analyze it as an adjective because *sidéré* here is likely about the end result, and not the action of sideration. But if it was a past participle, the clause would be using the verb *sidéré* in the infinitive present in the passive voice, and this would lead to the same agreement with the subject.)

So, if the implicit subject X is singular masculine (or non-gender-committing), it's *sidéré*. If X is singular feminine, it's *sidérée*. If X is plural masculine (or mixed or non-gender-committing), it's *sidérés*. If X is plural feminine, it's *sidérées*. Modern non-gender-committing forms also include *sidéré(e)* (singular) and *sidéré(e)s* (plural).

Presumably the speaker includes non only himself (or herself) but also his/her audience or other people. The implicit X is *nous*: “*Impossible [pour nous] de ne pas être sidérés*”. Therefore *sidérés* has a plural agreement.

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie On fait l'accord parce que l'attribut du sujet s'accorde avec le sujet. Mais il faut comprendre qu'il y a bien un sujet, même síl est implicite et même si le verbe est à l'infinitif qui n'a en général pas de sujet.

Answer (score 1):

This is so because in the context where these words are found they constitute a  true sentence in which a part has been ellipted. The full sentence would be like the following (I don't see too many options).

- **Il nous est** impossible  de ne pas être sidérés, cette semaine.

The real subject being "nous" (a plural), there is a plural for "sidéré". If "nous" stood for women only, you'd have "**sidérées**".

Comment: added the full quote

Comment: @LeeviL All you have to do is add "Il nous est" in front of it and you obtain a correct sentence,or more precisely, the most sensible completing phrase that does not change the meaning and makes the construction more usual.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gilles' explanation but I'd like to add that when it is intended to be a generic statement, i.e. the person speaking does not restrict the feeling to himself or a group of people he belongs to but to an indefinite amount of people, the singular can be used so:

> [Il est] impossible de ne pas être sidéré, cette semaine...

is fully acceptable.

There is no evidence the author consider only a group of people are *sidérés* so the sentence implies more ***il est** impossible...* than ***il nous** est impossible...*

The singular is actually by far much more frequent than the plural in this kind of statement.

> *Malgré les lignes heurtées, bizarres et les coups de haches de leur dos, de leurs jambes et de leur encolure, il est **impossible de ne pas être ravi** et pour ainsi dire **attendri** de l'expression intelligente, naïve et tendre de ces têtes de petits chameaux dans leur enfance.*
> *Nouveau voyage en Orient*, Lamartine, 1850

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie Je me l'explique avec un raisonnement un peu similaire à celui qui fait utiliser le singulier dans une phrase comme: *Il est interdit aux visiteurs ne ne pas mettre un masque*. Dans la phrase de l'OP, chacun a sa propre sidération. L'usage le plus courant est bien le singulier. *Sidéré* étant trop rare, j'ai fait des recherches avec des adjectifs plus courants et par exemple Google ne trouve que cinq occurrence d'**impossible de ne pas être fascinés** contre des centaines d'**impossible de ne pas être fasciné**.

Comment: Le propos est une généralité puisque l'auteur indique qu'il s'applique à tout le monde.

Comment: Le *s* indique un nombre de personnes en état de sidération (le locuteur observe un groupe, il peut partager ou non leur émotion), sans ce *s*, c'est l'état du groupe de ces mêmes personnes qui partagent la même émotion qui est envisagé  : le locuteur s'inclut dans ce groupe, s'identifie aux personnes, ils ne font qu'*un*.

Comment: @Personne J'en conclus que le *s* n'est pas attendu dans cette phrase puisque l'auteur fait forcément partie du groupe, ne le limitant pas.

Comment: Oui, mais l'utilisation du verbe *être* et du nom *être* (neutre en plus) me fait réécrire ma première proposition : Le *s* indique un nombre de personnes en état de sidération (le locuteur observe un groupe dans lequel il y a des personnes en état de sidération et d'autres non, il peut partager ou non leur émotion), le premier sous-entendu de l'oralité de la phrase transcrite « il est impossible de ne pas être sidérés *à cet endroit*, pour exprimer l'empathie alors qu'après réflexion ont écrit "qu'ils ne soient pas" », …

Comment: … le second sous-entendu de l'oralité de la phrase transcrite « il est impossible de ne pas être sidérés, *eux là-bas/avant et moi ici/maintenant* (au moins 2 groupes ou êtres différenciés) et c'est peut-être pourquoi la personne qui a fait la transcription a intuitivement mis un *s*, c'est alors un témoignage d'empathie que l'on peut nommer faute de frappe, ce qui doit être pour  M. Grevisse une faute à ne surtout commettre dans le monde académique, en revanche, pourrait s'écrire dans un poème, indiquant ainsi la façon d'interpréter la musique des mots.

Answer (score 0):

C'est un détail, mais le [document](https://www.franceculture.fr/medias/invasion-du-capitole-inceste-astrologie-et-jacques-prevert-la-session-de-rattrapage) a la forme d'une infolettre hebdomadaire personnalisée et commence par « Bonjour à toutes et à tous », assurément une [coordination](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3997) de deux pluriels qui serait représentée par un masculin pluriel. Suit immédiatement la phrase avec l'accord au pluriel. Quand le sujet est [sous-entendu](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3836), c'est le contexte qui indique l'accord de l'adjectif/participe passé attribut du sujet (BDL, LBU14 § 248), que le verbe soit conjugué ou non, et parfois plusieurs sujets implicites peuvent être donneurs et on peut choisir. À mon avis, vu le style qui ressemble à un courriel adressé à des abonnés, il serait incongru de choisir le singulier dans la phrase suivant immédiatement un [doublet](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4542) (pluriel) en appel. Et pour réussir à s'exprimer de manière très générale en faisant abstraction du pluriel qui précède ici, on s'attendrait à une précision comme « à/pour quiconque » afin d'infirmer le trompe-l’œil du nombre pour ainsi dire, a fortiori dans une phrase qui n'a pas à première vue les caractéristiques (sémantiquement parlant) d'une affirmation universelle ou d'une prescription. Je résumerais en disant qu'il me semble que c'est davantage par cohérence que par contrainte grammaticale que l'on a fait le choix du pluriel.